# How to pass values in a mutator (setter) method for a 2D Character array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, setter

So I have creates this method,

```
   public void setarray(char[][]a)
   {
     board=a;
   }
```

and want to pass values 3 and 3 in the 2D array through my Main function.

```
    test.setRow(3);
    test.setCol(3);
    test.setarray[][]
```

Basically the the Row and Col values which are set to 3, should be consumed by that array.

How do I do that? I am getting an error.

Comment: Show us the code where you get the error.

Comment: And also describe what the error says.

Comment: This is the code block with error:

Comment: //an object of the Tic Tac Toe called gameBoard created
        TicTacToe test = new TicTacToe();
        test.setRow(3);
        test.setCol(3);
        test.setarray[][];

Comment: Error says: Cannot resolve symbol 'setarray'.